# Independent contractor for a Canadian company with no 1099 for 6 months then under US payroll with W-2. What to do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-w-2, turbotax

I am a US permanent resident and I was working for a Canadian company as an independent contractor for the first half of 2015 without any 1099s and they wire transfer my wages directly into my US bank account. Then after 6 months, the company opened its US branch so for the second half of 2015 I was under US payroll and I received W-2 form.

I have already entered my W-2 form's info in **TurboTax** and entered the total wages for the first 6 months by checking **Foreign or international organizations** and filling the **Total self-employed wages**.

I am not sure if I did this correctly or maybe I should file Schedule-C! But given the fact that I am not a business owner nor a freelancer, I think that I shouldn't file Schedule-C. Again for the first 6 months I don't have 1099s or anything else. Now the thing which bothers me is that TurboTax shows the total income of W-2 form as my total income but I think my total income should be the total income of W-2 form plus my income from the first half of 2015. Is this correct?

Am I doing it correctly by just entering the self employment wages? Or I should do s.t. different?